# How to set a good background for Interior Bathroom scene and Critiques

Tags: rendering, lighting

[image: No area light, only light from plane and ceiling]

[image: Plane Light]

[image: Like this ?]

Both pictures above have been photoshopped to add the trees image, I wanna know what's the better way because I don't feel like it's blending in correctly
Also Let me know if there's anything else that I should Change
Thank You.

[image: Update 2]

[image: Update 3]

Update 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any problem with lights, what disturbs me though is that the perspective lines don't seem to match. For example for the first picture, unless the background of the landscape is supposed to be a small hill, which doesn't seem to be the case, the horizon line of this landscape should be much lower, so maybe move it down:

[image]

Also make sure that you don't overlap the bottom of the blinds with the horizon:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, I tried what you said and updated the post with that image, did you meant this way ? also how can I find images like these easily or any easy way to fill the background, and thanks for confirming lighting, I was afraid the client wouldn't like it

Comment: yes but make sure that the horizon does not align with the bottom of the window blinds

Comment: do you mean it's correct now or I need to match the horizon with bottom of window seal, like it needs to be tilted with respect to blind bottom

Comment: no I mean it's visually strange that the horizon is aligned with the bottom of the blind, so you need to unaligned the two lines, either moving up or donw the horizon or moving up or down the blind, first I thought the horizon should be higher (given the green lines I've drawn), but actually maybe lower down the horizon and keep the blind where it is? Another thing that is good imho is that we now see a brighter part of your landscape and it creates a kind of volumetric effect which is good, it gives depth to space

Comment: I see, made another update, you're right it gives that volumetric effect, and I feel like it also changed the focus element for the image, Never thought making minor changes would bring this much of a difference in it

Comment: yes I think it's much better now, maybe the blinds should not cut the window at it exact half though, move it up a bit

Comment: Done, Looking Better now ?

Comment: I think so, maybe check the vanishing lines (like i've done in the first picture) to see if it matches the horizon line?

Comment: I checked and Its Extremely close to the mountain in left so I feel like horizon is like almost perfect

Comment: So I guess it's probably good, maybe the wall on the right needs a bit of reflection, depending on its material, but it's a detail

Comment: tried adding reflection but due to glass it's not showing that clearly